# Magento 2 installation giving "Vendor autoload is not found"

Tags: magento2, error, installation, composer, varien-autoload

I have uploaded **Magento2** source code on `centos Rackspace server`, and I have changed credentials whenever required. However, when I run my website, I get an error:

> Vendor autoload is not found.
>
> Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

After this, I installed composer, but still, I get this error.

URL: http://204.232.133.184/

Comment: Your link is not opening. If possibe upload screen shot.

Comment: @ravi just delete the all inside the cache folder except .htacess  and .sample-data-state.flag and provide proper permission to all your folder

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in Magento 2 root directories:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Before you do that, go to your Magento root directory and run `composer install`. You cloned the Magento 2 GitHub repository and that command downloads all the dependent modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following command to fix the issue

1- chmod -R 755 pub var app/etc

2- use command composer install

Note: Please make sure that your composer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing vendor, you need to upload vendor or run below command for download vendor

```
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands to solve this issue:

```
1. Download the composer phar file using below link
https://getcomposer.org/download/
```

Run all the mentioned commands one by one in the putty

```
2. php composer.phar install
```

Once both commands ran successfully then refresh frontend, it will ask for setup.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to automatically download the composer and use it.

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
chmod +x composer.phar
./composer.phar install
```